# How to install PhoneGap?

Tags: windows-8, cordova

I am completely new for PhoneGap. I want to learn how to install it on my windows 8 operating system machine. I want guide to how start my work. I am curious about work with PhoneGap.

Comment: First have a look at the [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) page. They have really nice tutorials.

Comment: Look at this: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.2.0/guide_getting-started_windows-8_index.md.html it's what you are looking for.

Comment: First, spell PhoneGap correctly; it will help you search for information. Secondly, read the FAQ and [what not to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/dont-ask) pages of this site to understand why a broad question like this is not encouraged here.

Comment: I do all the setup for that,but then for run code visual studio 2012 express for windows8 IDE is give me error that purchase developer lic. now how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It won't be easy for people to answer your question here: it's too vague, and there's no definitive answer.

If you are new to any technology you should always start by doing your own research online, follow through any tutorials available, and then post questions on Stack Overflow as you come across specific problems or issues that we can help with.

In this instance [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) has very [well-written and detailed sets of documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/index.html) to help with first-time users.  In particular, a detailed and easy-to-follow [Getting Started guide](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/guide_getting-started_index.md.html#Getting%20Started%20Guides).

There's also a vibrant and helpful [community](http://phonegap.com/community/) with [tutorials](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.7.0/index.html), videos, [events](http://phonegap.com/event/), [blog](http://phonegap.com/blog/phonegap/) and [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/phonegap).

I found all of that with [one Google search](http://www.google.com/?q=phonegap). Have you tried any of that?